# Adding columns to a .csv in Python

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to add column to a .csv file, so what I do is open the file and write a new one. As I want to repeat the same format for a lot of columns I've created a function inside, I call it later with the different values.

The problem it's that only the first one which is `values(0, 0, 0)` it's written at the new .csv and all the other ones are not executed and not written in the .csv file. Why is this happening?

```py
def calculate_haralick(self, directory_segmentation: str, directory_originals: str,
                       n_displays: int,
                       font_path: str, font_size: int, image_dict: dict, color_plaque: str):

    with open('results_output_t3.csv', 'r') as read_object, \
            open('results_output_t4.csv', 'w', newline='') as write_object:
        csv_reader = reader(read_object)
        csv_writer = writer(write_object)

        def values(number, distance, theta):
            line_count = 0
            for row in csv_reader:
                if line_count == 0:
                    row.append('contrast' + str(number))
                    row.append('dissimilarity' + str(number))
                    row.append('homogeneity' + str(number))
                    row.append('ASM' + str(number))
                    row.append('energy' + str(number))
                    row.append('correlation' + str(number))
                    csv_writer.writerow(row)
                    line_count += 1
                    continue
                line_count += 1

                first_col_value = ""
                second_col_value = ''
                third_col_value = ''
                fourth_col_value = ''
                fifth_col_value = ''
                sixth_col_value = ''
                image_name = row[1]
                image_path_seg = os.path.join(directory_segmentation, image_name)
                image_path_orig = os.path.join(directory_originals, image_name)
                if os.path.exists(image_path_seg):
                    segmented_image = cv2.imread(image_path_seg)
                    original = cv2.imread(image_path_orig)
                    first_col_value = har_des.TextureWavelets().find_intersection(color_plaque, segmented_image,
                                                                                  original, distance, theta,
                                                                                  'contrast')
                    second_col_value = har_des.TextureWavelets().find_intersection(color_plaque, segmented_image,
                                                                                   original, distance, theta,
                                                                                   'dissimilarity')
                    third_col_value = har_des.TextureWavelets().find_intersection(color_plaque, segmented_image,
                                                                                  original, distance, theta,
                                                                                  'homogeneity')
                    fourth_col_value = har_des.TextureWavelets().find_intersection(color_plaque, segmented_image,
                                                                                   original, distance, theta, 'ASM')
                    fifth_col_value = har_des.TextureWavelets().find_intersection(color_plaque, segmented_image,
                                                                                  original, distance, theta,
                                                                                  'energy')
                    sixth_col_value = har_des.TextureWavelets().find_intersection(color_plaque, segmented_image,
                                                                                  original, distance, theta,
                                                                                  'correlation')
                row.append(first_col_value)
                row.append(second_col_value)
                row.append(third_col_value)
                row.append(fourth_col_value)
                row.append(fifth_col_value)
                row.append(sixth_col_value)

                csv_writer.writerow(row)

        values(0, 0, 0)
        values(1, 2, 0.5)
        values(2, 3, 0.5)
        values(3, 4, 0.5)
        values(4, 5, 0.5)
        values(5, 2, 0.8)
        values(6, 3, 0.8)
        values(7, 4, 0.8)
        values(8, 5, 0.8)
        values(9, 2, 3.14)
        values(10, 3, 3.14)
        values(11, 4, 3.14)
        values(12, 5, 3.14)
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and easiest way will be to use the pandas library.

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv("results_output_t3.csv")
df["new_column_name_1"] = ""
df["new_column_name_2"] = ""

df.to_csv("results_output_t4.csv")
```

Comment: But the problem is that the function `code` values is only executing once and not all the times I call it:(